# I am having trouble with a palindrome function in javascript

Tags: javascript, palindrome

This is my code: 
   The function works well for inputs: "eye","race car","not a palindrome","A man, a plan, a canal. Panama","never odd or even"...
However, it returns "true" when the input is "almostomla". Can someone please explain why?

```
function palindrome(str) {

  var newStr = str.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, '');
  newStr = newStr.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  newStr = newStr.toLowerCase();
  var arr = newStr.split('');
  var arr2 =[];

  for(x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
    arr2.push(arr[arr.length-1-x]);
  }

  for(y = 0; y < arr.length; y++){
    if(arr[y] == arr2[y]){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }

}

palindrome("almostomla");
```

Comment: `"ever odd or even"` is not a palindrome!

Comment: sorry, spelling error. the input was "never odd or even"

Comment: Just running a few quick checks, your function seems to return true based ONLY on the criteria that the first and last letter in the input are the same. Even something like "a3458udfhfuhwekthua" returns TRUE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of one of these many other [palindrome questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=palindrome+javascript).

Comment: Your code will say, `Praveen Kumar P` is also a Palindrome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would really replace the palindrome checking function like below, after removing noise:

```js
function palindrome(str) {
  var newStr = str.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, '');
  newStr = newStr.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  newStr = newStr.toLowerCase();
  var arr = newStr.split('');
  return arr.join('') == arr.reverse().join('');
}

alert(palindrome("almostomla"));
alert(palindrome("never odd or even"));
```

Works as expected.

**Why doesn't your old code work?**

It checks only the first correct thing and returns `true`. You should remove the `return true` from there. Your code is **as soon as first and last character are same, consider it as palindrome**.

So your code, corrected form will be:

```js
function palindrome(str) {

  var newStr = str.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, '');
  newStr = newStr.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  newStr = newStr.toLowerCase();
  var arr = newStr.split('');
  var arr2 = [];

  for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    arr2.push(arr[arr.length - 1 - x]);
  }

  for (var y = 0; y < arr.length; y++) {
    debugger;
    if (arr[y] != arr2[y]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true; // Place it here to return after the whole loop.
}

alert(palindrome("almostomla"));
alert(palindrome("never odd or even"));
```

Comment: Why not `return newStr == newStr.split('').reverse().join('');`?

Comment: @AKS That's my first one.

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking first and last characters in your last for loop.

```
for(y = 0; y < arr.length; y++){
    if(arr[y] == arr2[y]){ //if first and last chars equal you are returning true.
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
}
```

You should check all characters until a difference or the end.

```
for(y = 0; y < arr.length; y++){
    if(arr[y] != arr2[y]){
      return false;
    }
}

return true; --that means two arrays are same.
```

Comment: yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing out my error. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use a simpler function to check if a word is palindrome:

```
function checkPalindrom(str) {
    return str == str.split('').reverse().join('');
}

checkPalindrom("almostomla"); // false
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the spaces and comma presented things.

Comment: yes, I am aware I could have written it like that. Thank you! I would, however, like to know why my previous version is not working :)

Comment: I think it can be assumed that the OP will take care of it before comparing. What @Carlos provided is an idea over which the OP can work on.

Comment: @sallysway Your logic is wrong. See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar Thank you very much  :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do this:

```
function palindrome(str) {

  var isPalindrome = true;
  var newStr = str.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g, '');
  newStr = newStr.replace(/\s+/g, '');
  newStr = newStr.toLowerCase();
  var arr = newStr.split('');

  for(x = 0; x < arr.length / 2; x++) {
      if(arr[x] != arr[arr.length - 1 - x])
      {
          isPalindrome = false;
          break;
      }
  }    

  return isPalindrome;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning just after comparing the first entry:

```
for(y = 0; y < arr.length; y++){
    if(arr[y] == arr2[y]){
      return true; // here you are returning
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

So in case of `almostomla` the first element of both `arr` and `arr2` is `a` because the string starts and ends with `a`.

You can do it like this to check the first entry which doesn't match:

```
var flag = true;

  for(y = 0; y < arr.length; y++){
    if(arr[y] != arr2[y]){
      flag= false;
      break;
    }
  }

return flag;
```

Answer (score 0):

You compare the first and the last letter. If they are the same, then the code returns "True" without checking other letters in the string. The comparisons should continue even though the first iteration of the loop yields "True"!